How to recognise a Kármán-Pohlhausen problem
I'm working on a problem,

A fluid moves in a steady two-dimensional flow in the region defined by $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$. The boundary with equation $y=0$ is occupied by a stationary flat plate. Given that the $x$ component of velocity $u\rightarrow U$ as $y\rightarrow\infty$, where $U$ is a constant, write down the expressions for the displacement thickness $\delta_1$ and the momentum thickness $\delta_2$.

The given solution is $$\delta_1=\int_0^\delta1-\frac{u}{U}\text{ d}y,\hspace{2em} \delta_2=\int_0^\delta\frac{u}{U}\left(1-\frac{u}{U}\right)\text{ d}y.$$
I recognise these expressions with an upper limit of $\delta$ as an application of the Kármán-Pohlhausen method, with $\delta$ being the supposed definite thickness of the boundary layer. But earlier the course notes give the general definition, $$\delta_1=\int_0^\infty1-\frac{u}{U}\text{ d}y,\hspace{2em} \delta_2=\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{U}\left(1-\frac{u}{U}\right)\text{ d}y.$$ Is there something about the ansatz that should have told me to use an upper limit of $\delta$ rather than $\infty$?
